# Conjecture related to the Erdős discrepancy problem

Tags: number-theory, open-problem, multiplicative-function

Conjecture: If $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $S$ is an infinite set of primes, then the multiplicative $\pm$-sequence generated by $S$ contains $+^k$ as a substring infinitely often.  (If $S$ is allowed to be finite then this fails for example with $S=\{2\}$ and $k=4$.)  In other words, we have a totally multiplicative function $f$ such that $f(p) = -1$ whenever $p \in S$ and $f(p) = 1$ for all other primes, so all the other values are determined to be $-1$ or $1$, and we wish to show that there are an infinite number of starting points $x_0$ such that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \{x_0, \dots, x_0 + k - 1\}$.

## 1. This would imply the multiplicative variant of the EDP, but it is a seemingly stronger statement, so I wonder if there are any counterexamples?

I'm particularly interested in the case $S = \mathbb{P}$.  For $k=2$, we are trying to show there are an infinite number of consecutive pairs in which both numbers have an even number of prime factors counting multiplicity, or in terms of the Liouville function $\lambda(x) = \lambda(x+1) = 1$.  This case is implied by twin primes but that's not very satisfying.

## 2. What is an easy and straightforward way to prove the case $S = \mathbb{P}$ and $k = 2$?

## 3. Any hints for $S = \mathbb{P}$ and larger values of $k$?

Comment: You probably should define what you mean by "the multiplicative $\pm$-sequence generated by $S$".

Comment: Two ideas: (1) Spiro and a refinement by Heath-Brown showed that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ have the same number of divisors. That might be an entry point into the literature on consecutive values of multiplicative functions. (2) Now that we know (via Zhang/Maynard/Tao/Polymath) that any admissible $k$-tuple contains at least two primes infinitely often (when $k\ge105$ and somewhat better now), could we carefully choose a $k$-tuple and $k$ multipliers, a la the Spiro/Heath-Brown method, to generate solutions to $\lambda(n)=\lambda(n+1)=1$?

Comment: A third idea: use Littlewood-type ideas to show that the sums $\sum_{n\le x} \lambda(n)$ are unbounded above and below; this would imply that $\lambda(n)=\lambda(n+1)=1$ (and ${}=-1$) infinitely often.

Comment: We can get the weaker $\lambda(n) = \lambda(n+1) = \pm 1$ infinitely often using the pigeonhole principle (every prime gap containing an odd square must have either a $++$ or a $--$).  Thank you for all the references!

Comment: extending your idea, we can get $\lambda(n)=\lambda(n+1)=+1$ infinitely often by considering $k^4-1$ and $k^4$, since $\lambda(k^4)=1$. If $\lambda(k^4-1)=-1$, then that means exactly one of $\lambda(k^2-1)$ and $\lambda(k^2+1)$ equals $1$, and it can be paired with its neighbor $\lambda(k^2)=1$. I think this works for $k$ even or odd.

Comment: Nice, that answers question 2.